# How to implement 'if' on certain values?

Tags: jquery, if-statement

Again I'm new to jquery and am trying to get this office-space calculator to work. 
I want to use separate animation when my "`total`" value changes.
Like if `1` is selected and "`calculate`" is selected, play animation.

[Here where my widget is](http://clarencehouseuk.com/#accommodation)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#arrow-right').click(function () {
        if (parseInt($('#total').text()) < 3) {
          $('#total').text(parseInt($('#total').text()) + 1);
        }
    });
})
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#arrow-left').click(function () {
        if (parseInt($('#total').text()) > 1) {
           $('#total').text(parseInt($('#total').text()) - 1);
        }
    });
})
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#calculate").click(function () {
        if ('#total' == 1) {
            $("#requirements-contact").css("display", "block");
            $("#space-calculator").animate({
                height: '595px'
            }, "slow");
            var div = $("#space-total, #thousands, #hundreds, #tens, #units");
            div.animate({
                display: 'toggle'
            }, "slow");
            div.animate({
                bottom: '-895px'
            }, "slow");
            var div = $("#hundreds");
            div.animate({
                bottom: '-695px'
            }, "slow");
            var div = $("#tens");
            div.animate({
                bottom: '-395px'
            }, "slow");
            var div = $("#units");
            div.animate({
                bottom: '-195px'
            }, "slow");
        }
        if ('#total' == 2) {
            $("#requirements-contact").css("display", "block");
            $("#space-calculator").animate({
                height: '595px'
            }, "slow");
            var div = $("#space-total, #thousands, #hundreds, #tens, #units");
            div.animate({
                display: 'toggle'
            }, "slow");
            div.animate({
                bottom: '-895px'
            }, "slow");
            var div = $("#hundreds");
            div.animate({
                bottom: '-695px'
            }, "slow");
            var div = $("#tens");
            div.animate({
                bottom: '-395px'
            }, "slow");
            var div = $("#units");
            div.animate({
                bottom: '-195px'
            }, "slow");
        }
        if ('#total' == 3) {
            $("#requirements-contact").css("display", "block");
            $("#space-calculator").animate({
                height: '595px'
            }, "slow");
            var div = $("#space-total, #thousands, #hundreds, #tens, #units");
            div.animate({
                display: 'toggle'
            }, "slow");
            div.animate({
                bottom: '-895px'
            }, "slow");
            var div = $("#hundreds");
            div.animate({
                bottom: '-695px'
            }, "slow");
            var div = $("#tens");
            div.animate({
                bottom: '-395px'
            }, "slow");
            var div = $("#units");
            div.animate({
                bottom: '-195px'
            }, "slow");
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: How do I get the calculate button to play different animations when a different value is selected?

Comment: I think its here I'm going wrong:
if ('#total' == 1) {

I tried !=1 but all that seems to happen is the same animation plays: http://clarencehouseuk.com/#accommodation

I want each value to play a different animation when the #calculate button is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly what you need to do is: `$('#total').val()` if it is an editable input type element (like `<input id='total' type="text">`). If it is just a text inside of an element (like `<span id="total">1<div>') what you need to do is:`$('#total').text()` to get the text.

here is the full cod:

```
if ($('#total').val() == 3) {
  //do what you need to do...

}
```

or

```
 if ($('#total').text() == 3) {
      //do what you need to do...

 }
```

hope this is what you asked for.

Comment: Hi Vlad, yep that worked excellent, I had to change the .val to .text but yep, thank you for the help.